# how to divide a decimal number javascript

Tags: javascript

So this code adds up by **0.001** on each loop, i have it set to only show me 3 numbers past the decimal but on the 10th loop for example when it reaches **0.01** i want it to only show 2 numbers past the decimal, i dont need it to show the 0.

```
var Num = 0.000
for(s = 1; s <= 15; s++){
Num = Num + 0.001
var NumX = Num.toFixed(3)
if(NumX % 10 == 0){
var NumX = Num.toFixed(2)
alert("working")
}

}
```

I tried dividing by 10 in the above code but i dont know how to divide decimals can someone show me how to get this code to work, thanks.

Comment: You can check out answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715819/divide-number-with-decimals-javascript

Comment: So when it reaches 0.011, you want it to show 0.01?

Comment: If you can, avoid computation with floating point values. You might not get the expected result due to precision errors. Why not use whole numbers?

Comment: @numbermaniac No only when it reaches a number like 0.20 where the 3rd number after decimal would be a 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
var NumX = Num.toFixed( s%10==0 ? 2 : 3 );
```

That is, decide how many decimal places to show based on the value of `s`.