# How does Android calculate the layout_weight in pixels?

Tags: android, layout, view, pixel

I divide a LinearLayout into say 7 different Views using weight_sum = 7 and the Views each have layout_weight = 1.
The whole LinearLayout spans over 100 pixels on the device.

100 pixels / 7 = 14.29 pixels.
Since pixels can only be integers the actual size in pixels of the 7 child views will be like this:

14 - 14 - 14 - 14 - 14 - 15 - 15

I'm now wondering which formula Android uses to calculate where to round down and where to round up.

For positioning, I would need to know it for any LinearLayout of size x with y child views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/LinearLayout.java#LinearLayout.onMeasure%28int,int%29), it casts the division to an `int`. See line 441.

Therefore, it always takes the floor integer value

Answer (score 0):

If you see in the source of [LinearLayout](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/LinearLayout.java)  you can see that it is using simple `Math.Max` function to do simple calculation like this. more related info you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577427/evenly-divide-in-c-sharp)